# Unable to download the file in its original format from Postgres

Tags: spring, postgresql

I have uploaded some files with their filenames into postgres using Spring API calls , and some of the files are named as
Copy 1.txt
Abc now.doc
So when send GET request from postman the download popup shows only "Copy" and "Abc" and extension to be all (*.*)
The request is working for filenames without a whitespace or if I replace the whitespace with some character like _ (underscore).
Please suggest what I can do for such files if I want the name to be with the whitespace.

Comment: Please add the code you are using to send the files. You probably need to url-encode the filenames before sending it (as space is a special character in HTML).

Comment: Thanks. This needs to be done.